# Make a C program write to standard output even though it requires a filename for its output

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I have a C program that takes an output file name and dumps data into it. Most probably the program uses FILE* pointers. Is it possible to pass terminal stdout to that C program? I do not have access to the code.

What I mean, the program works as follows --

```
> ./program out.txt # --> dumps data into out.txt
```

What I want to do is something like --

```
> ./program &1 # --> dumps data on the terminal.
```

Is it possible? How can it be done?

Comment: In other words, you want the program to deliver output to terminal's stdout instead of file?

Comment: I got my answer, but thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `/dev/stdout` or `/dev/fd/1`.

```
./program /dev/stdout
```

Comment: Many programs will write to standard output if not given a file to write to.  It is not clear from the question whether that's the case with this program — it probably isn't, in fact.  But it shows a bit of carelessness in the design of the program.  There's also, in Bash, `./program >(cat)` if a system doesn't support `/dev/stdout` (which is pretty improbable, but not impossible — though, come to think of it, process substitution probably depends on the `dev/fd` pseudo-filesystem anyway).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Most programs use filename arguments for input, and default to stdin when there are no filenames. For programs that take a filename argument for output, there's less of a concensus. Many accept `-` as a placeholder to mean write to stdout. But `/dev/stdout` is a way to deal with any program that requires a filename argument.

Comment: Agreed; it is less usual to take an output file (but not unheard of; `tar`, `gcc`, `sort` to name but 3 all have output file arguments — and two of them even agree on the option used to specify the output file name!).  I was trying to complement rather than diss your answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the program explicitly asks a file name, that's why this question. I agree with your point about the carelessness.